# Automating RESTful Testing

Tags: rest, automated-tests

I am trying to automate the testing of RESTful services, and researching tools that would be easy to setup and maintain. Basically, I would like to supply the endpoints (can be `POST`, `PUT`, `GET`, `DELETE`, etc.), along with various parameters/headers - like [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) does, but only in a batch, automated manner.

My tests would pass for a `200`, and fail for any other HTTP return code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://htt.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/cwiki/bin/public

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home

http://jmeter.apache.org/

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/curl.htm

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/